# Why is catch block executed twice for a single exception?

Tags: java, swing, exception

I have the following code.

```
try{
    Twitter twitter = new Twitter(user,password);
    twitter.setStatus(txtStatus.getText());

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success");
    txtStatus.setText("");
    txtStatus.requestFocus();

}catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Some Error.\n" +
                    " If you see this after Success Message..Ignore");
}
```

Here even after I get "Success message" Dialog, the "Some Error" dialog is also appearing. what may be the reason? Shouldnt the flow control escape the catch block if there were no run time errors.

Even if i get an exception also, the "Some Error" dialog is appearing twice.Why is this happenning?

Comment: how about the actual printStack ?

Comment: Pro tip: **NEVER `catch Exception` like this**. If you do, your catch clause will be like a box of chocolates - you never know what you gonna get.

Comment: *Never say never* - there are a couple of places you may want to do a `catch Exception` or even a `catch Throwable`. In framework code, wrapping code that calls a component with a broad catch statement prevents the entire framework from failing due to one component.  Also, this case where it's more 'error reporting' than 'error handling' - though this specific code is a bad example, because there's no way of knowing exactly what the error actually is.  Usually 'error reporting' is done in one place globally in the app if possible, and sometimes the error is wrapped/rethrown if needed.

Answer (score 8):

You've left open the obvious possibility that one of the lines of code *after* the success dialog is displayed is throwing an exception. You're not catching a specific exception and you're not displaying a backtrace, so there's no way of telling. Start your debugging by using the caught exception's `printStackTrace` method to find out where it's coming from.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the Exception that you're catching and its stack trace, and you may be enlightened.

My guess: `txtStatus` is null after your first dialog, or it's the `requestFocus()` method that throws an Exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your code may actually be called twice. Try putting a System.out.println statement at the top of the code or running it under a debugger and check it is actually only being called once.

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the stack `e.printStackTrace()` - there might be an exception after the success message (e.g. a `NullPointerException` with `txtStatus`?)

Comment: No, use of `txtStatus` can not throw a `NullPointerException`, it’s already used before the first dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Exception can be thrown in one of this two lines:

```
txtStatus.setText("");
txtStatus.requestFocus();
```

Comment: If it's showMessageDialog() that is throwing the exception than nothing is going to be displayed unless it's and exception that is specific to the case when second parameter is "Success".

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your thought... I believe that if lakshmanan see the success message, than the problem is not in this line. It remains only two lines of code that can throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with atomice here:  your code is being called multiple times.  Add the finally block + more sensible error feedback.

```
try{
    Twitter twitter = new Twitter(user,password);
    twitter.setStatus(txtStatus.getText());

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success");
    txtStatus.setText("");
    txtStatus.requestFocus();

}
catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Some Error.\n" + e.getMessage());
}
finally {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Finally");
}
```

Comment: I checked your solution, it shows "Finally" dialog after success message, then again it shows "Some Error" and "Finally" dialog. This is the order i get
Success Dialog

Finally Dialog

Some Error Dialog

Finally Dialog

Comment: There you go.  That means that you are not (as expected and contrary to what you thought) getting both a success and error message in on iteration over the block:  It is getting called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

And I'll throw my two cents in as well.

Stick a break point on the first line and watch it with a debugger.  You'll quickly see if it is being run twice, if something is null, and where the error is.

The debugger is your friend :-)

Comment: I checked it in Debugger mode, the above actually is in an actionPerformed() method (event listener on a button click event). the same method is executed twice ....

Comment: I have an actionListener class(responding to a button click event) and there is the actionPerformed() method. The above code is the only code in that method. Why is this getting executed twice ??